Prevent DDL for Constraint from creating new index
I am using Oracle 19c database.  I have some constraints and I want to get the DDL.  Usually it looks like this:
  ALTER TABLE "MY_OWNER"."MY_TABLE1" ADD CONSTRAINT "MY_CONSTRAINT1" UNIQUE ("NAME", "ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE ...

Notice it does not explicitly create a new named index.
However, for some constraints (not sure what's the difference), it explicitly creates the index, like this:
  ALTER TABLE "MY_OWNER"."MY_TABLE2" ADD CONSTRAINT "MY_CONSTRAINT2" UNIQUE ("NAME", "ID")
  USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "MY_OWNER"."MY_INDEX2" ON "MY_OWNER"."MY_TABLE2" ("NAME", "ID") ...
  

I am already creating the index, and so this causes ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object errors when I try to run it.
What is different about the constraint in the 2nd case?  How do I get the DDL to not also CREATE UNIQUE INDEX?

How are you generating/ getting the DDL?

PK/UK constraint indexes can be pre-created standalone or implicitly created by the constraint itself.
If pre-created, when the constraint is added it simply "adopts" the index, but remembers that it was created separately. When you disable or drop the constraint, it does nothing to the index, which is treated as a separate object. This is commonly used to take advantage of the performance benefit of being able to create an index with parallelism, something not possible with a constraint DDL.
If the index is implicitly created when the constraint is added, it owns the index in a closer manner, such that disabling or dropping the constraint will automatically drop the underlying index. So this is simpler, but you can't use parallelism for that index build.
The fact is, we live in a world where we will encounter both situations, and yes, it is a bit of a headache. You can tell which is the case by examining dba_indexes.constraint_index (YES or NO), which you can use for any self-generated DDL to recreate the proper DDL that distinguishes between these two cases.
For dbms_metadata however, there is a known problem. It's not consistent, and I encountered the same thing in my own schema replication code. I have embedded in my code the following snippet:
          /*
          ** dbms_metadata incorrectly generates the wrong DDL for auto-generated constraint indexes and can create several variations of the USING INDEX clause. Standardize by remove the USING INDEX clause entirely.
          */
          var_ddls(i).ddltext := REGEXP_REPLACE(var_ddls(i).ddltext,'USING INDEX.*(ENABLE|DISABLE)','\1',1,0,'n');

So it appears I had to string manipulate this out of the DDL, which presumably means I was unable to find a transform that natively fixed the issue. That's not a surprise: across all object types there were several situations where manipulating the string to "fix" dbms_metadata output was necessary.
Another thing to try: if it turns out that dbms_metadata is doing this only for non-constraint indexes, then you also have the option of not pre-creating these indexes. Check for them in dba_constraints.index_owner/index_name and if found, don't create the index, so that when your later constraint DDL runs it doesn't error out. Worth a try if you'd prefer not to manipulate the constraint DDL as above.

Thanks @Paul W. Yes, I am using dbms_metadata.  I gave the last suggestion a try -- not creating indexes if they also appeared in dba_constraints.index_owner/index_name.  However, upon checking, several named indexes did not get created.

@ocarlen, that's what I was afraid of. That must be why I wrote that code comment about it not being consistent. Sounds like stripping out the USING INDEX clause from the DDL may be the right thing to do. Fortunately easy enough to do with REGEXP_REPLACE
